# Printing the logged in username in PHP. "Hi, $username, welcome back!"

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

this question may seem simple but I have been stuck on it for 3 hours.

Scenario:
An end-user logs into my website.

Question:
How can I print his credentials and store it as a variable?

I have been looking aimlessly and all I see is 50 lines of code with $_SESSION with using multiple php files.

In one page, can I grab the username and store it in a variable... done, thats all.

Thank you in advanced for your responses. Here is my code, you can check the comments to help you out.

```
    <?php
class modProfilePrintHelper
{


    public static function getHello( $params )
    {

//GRAB USERNAME THAT IS LOGGED IN
//STORE USERNAME IN VARIABLE

            //Obtain a database connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
//Retrieve the shout TOTAL
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select($db->quoteName('smiles'))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__smiles_users'))
            ->where('username = '. $db->Quote('USERNAME VARIABLE HERE'));
//Prepare the query
$db->setQuery($query);
// Load the row.
$result = $db->loadResult();
//Return
echo "<h3>";
echo 'Your Number of Smiles: ';
echo "</h3>";
echo '<font size = "5"><h1>' . $result . '</h1></font>' . '<br>';

    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

Joomla users will be available using User Object.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo 'Hello ,'.$user->name;
```

More about [user object in Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object)

For using session variables in Joomla, do not try with normal session use Joomla session library.

like below.

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('variable','your_value');
echo $session->get('variable');
```

[Joomla session Objects](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getSession)

Hope it helps..

Comment: I feel like giving you a virtual high five. Thank you so much for the assist!